# dll not getting generated

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have this code below which generates dll dynamically. This code works fine on windows form application

```
        var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        var options = new CompilerParameters
        {
            OutputAssembly = "MyTestDll.dll"

        };
        options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(@"c:\MyFolder\MyTestDll.dll");
        string testsource = "public class Foo {}";

        provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, new[] { testsource });
```

But when i put same code in my web application then it doesnt generate any dll file. What could be reason for this? I have never generated dll files on fly so i am not so much aware of this.

Comment: Are you sure the user running the web app has enough privileges to create the file on that folder? Try doing the same on a folder within the web app and see what happens.

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos do you mean on inetpub? User is none than me. I am running application from my project

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos Also i am writing file to same folder as i do in windows application. There it doesnt give me any issues

Comment: You mentioned a web application. This runs with a generic user ASP something. This user must have the right to write on the folder you specify. It doesn't matter who is using the web application.

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos can you tell me generic path? i tried saving unders inetpub as well but doesnt save

Comment: Where is your web application deployed?

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos its under inetpub

Comment: Try within your application's folder... Like `C:\InetPub\www\YourApplicationFolder`

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos i have tried but no luck

Comment: Do you get any kind of error?

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos i dont see any error in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve issue. I had to add path

```
OutputAssembly = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "MyTestDll.dll")
```

Then i commented away this line in my code

```
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(@"c:\MyFolder\MyTestDll.dll");
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a permissions issue it should give you an error when the application runs so this is probably a compiler error and you need to print that from the Errors property in the CompilerResults

Any errors would be in the Errors property of the CompilerResults returned from the CompileAssemblyFromSource method. Have you tried printing them out to see if there are errors ?

```
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, new[] { source });

foreach(CompilerError error in results.Errors)
{
      Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
}
```

Or if this is an ASP.NET page (since it's tagged asp.net) use Response.Write or set the error message to an ASP literal control.

Comment: I get this error "error CS1567: Error generating Win32 resource: Access is denied. "